# How to change default port 1433 on SQL Server in a node.js connection string

Tags: node.js, sql-server, connection-string

I changed the default port 1433 on my SQL Server in centos 7. But in API that is created with Node.js and uses the `mssql` package to connect to it, I get the error shown here when I want to send or get a request. `mssql` knows 1433 port as default.

My connection string

```
var sql = require('mssql');

var DbConnectionString = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'mypassword',
        server: 'serverip,newport',
        database: 'databasename',
    "options": {
    "encrypt": false,
    "enableArithAbort": true
    },    
};

module.exports = DbConnectionString;
```

And this is the error I get:

```
{
    "code": "ESOCKET",
    "originalError": {
        "message": "Failed to connect to myserverip,mynewport:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND myserverip,mynewport",
        "code": "ESOCKET"
    },
    "name": "ConnectionError"
}
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mssql docs](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#general-same-for-all-drivers) state that port can be specified with the 'port' key:

```
var DbConnectionString = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'mypassword',
    server: 'serverip',
    port: newport,
    database: 'databasename',
    "options": {
        "encrypt": false,
        "enableArithAbort": true
    },    
};
```

Comment: I added a small fix (port argument should be an integer). It worked for me.